# What is the smallest possible weighted average of 1...n?

Tags: inequality, summation

Let $a_1, ..., a_n$ be numbers in the range $[{1 \over n},1]$. Define:

$$ U = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i} $$

$$ W = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{i\cdot a_i} $$

I am looking for the largest possible value of the ratio $U \over W$, or equivalently:

**The smallest possible value of the weighted average of the numbers $1, ..., n$ with weights $a_1, ..., a_n$** (which is just $W \over U$).

Some simple cases:

- If all $a_i$'s are equal, then ${W \over U}={{n(n+1)} \over {2n}}=O(n)$.
- If $a_1=1$ and all other $a_i$'s are $1 \over n$, then again ${W \over U}={{1+O(n)} \over {1+O(1)}}=O(n)$.
- For every integer $k$ , if:

$$ a_i=1 \ \ \ \ \ (i\leq k)$$
$$ a_i={1 \over n} \ \ \ \ \ (i>k)$$

Then:
$$U = k + \frac{n-k}{n} > k$$
$$W = \sum_{i=1}^{k}{i} + {1 \over n}\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}{i}
< {k^2} + {n^2 \over n}$$

The largest ratio between these two expressions (up to a constant) is achieved by taking $k=\sqrt n$, which gives:

$$ {W \over U} \leq {2 \sqrt n} = O(\sqrt n)$$

MY QUESTIONS:

Is there a set of $a_1, ..., a_n$ for which the weighted average $W \over U$ is smaller than $O(\sqrt n)$?

EDIT: See a similar question here: [A non-linear optimization problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605388/a-non-linear-optimization-problem)

Comment: Lower bound or upper bound? If $a_1=1$ and the others are $0$ you get $n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry, I had a mistake in the question. Now it should be a lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can compute $U$ and $W$.

Take a $k$ such that you took and we have that $$U=\frac {nk+n-k}{n}$$ and $$W=\frac {nk^2+nk+n^2+n-k^2-k}{2n}$$. Now brute,part:

Find the $k$'s where you will have a minimum and a maximum with derivatives.

Comment: This maximizes the ratio only for specific sets of $a_i$'s (starting with $1$ and continuing with $1/n$). I am looking for the maximum for all possible sets of $a_i$'s.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi, yes but i think that the max and the min will be achieved with $1$ or $1/n$ values.

Comment: This is an interesting observation, but can you prove it?

Comment: (BTW, I did the arithmetic and the minimum is for $k=\frac{n^{3/2}-n}{n-1}=O(n^{1/2}$)

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi,very nice:). And sorry but I didn't have time to check it by my self.